# Alternative for GROUP BY and STUFF in SQL

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I am writing some `SQL` queries in `AWS Athena`. I have 3 tables `search`, `retrieval` and `intent`. In `search` table I have 2 columns id and term i.e.

```
id                 term
1                   abc
1                   bcd
2                   def
1                   ghd
```

What I want is to write a query to get:

```
id                  term
1               abc, bcd, ghd
2                    def
```

I know this can be done using `STUFF` and `FOR XML PATH` but, in Athena all the features of SQL are yet not supported. Is there any other way to achieve this. My current query is:

```
select search.id , STUFF(
   (select ',' + search.term
    from search
    FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')
FROM search
group by search.id
```

Also, I have one more question. I have `retrieval` table that consist of 3 columns i.e.:

```
id         time        term
1           0          abc
1           20         bcd
1           100        gfh
2           40         hfg
2           60         lkf
```

What I want is:

```
id          time       term
1           100        gfh
2            60        lkf
```

I want to write a query to get the `id` and `term` on the basis of `max` value of time. Here is my current query:

```
select retrieval.id, max(retrieval.time), retrieval.term
from search
group by retrieval.id, retrieval.term
order by max(retrieval.time)
```

I am getting duplicate id's along with the term. I think it is because, I am doing `group by` on id and term both. But, I am not sure how can I achieve it without using `group by`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XML method is brokenness in SQL Server.  No reason to attempt it in any other database.

One method uses arrays:

```
select s.id, array_agg(s.term)
from search s
group by s.id;
```

Because the database supports arrays, you should learn to use them.  You can convert the array to a string:

```
select s.id, array_join(array_agg(s.term), ',') as terms
from search s
group by s.id;
```

Comment: array_agg for Athena might return as well: bcd, ghd, abc. There is no ordering inside of group (which prestoDb is supporting)

Answer (score 0):

Group by is a group operation: think that you are clubbing the results and have to find min, max, count etc.
I am answering only one question. **Use it to find the answer to question 1**
For question 2:

```
select 
from (select id, max(time) as time
      from search
      group by id, term
      order by max(time)
) search_1, search as search_2
where search_1.id = search_2.id
and search_1.time = search_2.time
```

Comment: Where are you printing the term? I think this query will not work.